# jqGrid cellEdit Wrong Key Column Value

Tags: jquery, json, web-services, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

I'm using jqGrid to display Grid with the subGrid option, in the subGrid I marked a single column as the Key, the problem is that when I use remote cell edit, the rowid sent to the web-service is wrong (something like "jqg1"), while rowid in the "beforeSubmitCell" event is correct, help please, check my code below, thanks all....

```
$("#tb_JQ").jqGrid({
    url: "WebServices/WS_MonthlyFrcst.asmx/GetPlanGrouped",
    datatype: "JSON",
    postData: { PId: frcstId, PType: 1 },
    mtype: "POST",
    colNames: ["tableID", "Team", "Expense", "U/P", "Currency", "Quantity", "Value",
    "JAN", "Quantity", "FEB", "Quantity", "MAR", "Quantity", "APR", "Quantity", "MAY", "Quantity", "JUN", "Quantity",
    "JUL", "Quantity", "AUG", "Quantity", "SEP", "Quantity", "OCT", "Quantity", "NOV", "Quantity", "DEC", "Quantity"],
    colModel: [
        { name: "tableID", editable: false, key: true, hidden: true },
        { name: "Team", width: 80 }, { name: "License", index: 'License', width: 250 },
        { name: "UP", width: 75 }, { name: "Currency", width: 60 }, { name: "Quantity", width: 80 },
        { name: "Value", width: 80 },
        { name: "JAN", width: 75, hidden: true }, { name: "JAN_Quan", width: 60, hidden: true }, { name: "FEB", width: 75, hidden: true },
        { name: "FEB_Quan", width: 60, hidden: true }, { name: "MAR", width: 75, hidden: true }, { name: "MAR_Quan", width: 60, hidden: true },
        { name: "APR", width: 75, hidden: true }, { name: "APR_Quan", width: 60, hidden: true }, { name: "MAY", width: 75, hidden: true },
        { name: "MAY_Quan", width: 60, hidden: true }, { name: "JUN", width: 75, hidden: true }, { name: "JUN_Quan", width: 60, hidden: true },
        { name: "JUL", width: 75, hidden: true }, { name: "JUL_Quan", width: 60, hidden: true }, { name: "AUG", width: 75, hidden: true },
        { name: "AUG_Quan", width: 60, hidden: true }, { name: "SEP", width: 75, hidden: true }, { name: "SEP_Quan", width: 60, hidden: true },
        { name: "OCT", width: 75, hidden: true }, { name: "OCT_Quan", width: 60, hidden: true }, { name: "NOV", width: 75, hidden: true },
        { name: "NOV_Quan", width: 60, hidden: true }, { name: "DEC", width: 75, hidden: true }, { name: "DEC_Quan", width: 60, hidden: true }
        ],
    cmTemplate: { sortable: false, editable: false },
    viewrecords: true,
    width: 'auto',
    height: 'auto',
    loadonce: true,
    gridview: false,
    subGrid: true,
    caption: 'EXP',
    afterInsertRow: function (rowid, aData, rowElem) {
        // Some sort of boolean flag, maybe a row count on your sub grid data
        //alert(rowid);
        if (rowid == 'NoExpandExp') {
            $('#' + rowid).children("td.sgcollapsed").unbind().html("").removeClass("ui-sgcollapsed sgcollapsed");
        }
    },
    subGridRowExpanded: function (subgrid_id, row_id) {
        var rowData = $("#tb_JQ").getRowData(row_id);
        var team = rowData.tableID;
        var subgrid_table_id;
        subgrid_table_id = subgrid_id + "_t";
        var pager_id = "p_" + subgrid_table_id;
        var tempCellOldVal;

        $("#" + subgrid_id).html("<table id='" + subgrid_table_id + "' class='scroll'></table><div id='" + pager_id + "' class='scroll'></div>");
        jQuery("#" + subgrid_table_id).jqGrid({
            url: "WebServices/WS_MonthlyFrcst.asmx/GetBudgetBrkDown",
            datatype: "JSON",
            mtype: "POST",
            colNames: ["EntryId", "Team", "Expense", "U/P", "Currency", "Quantity", "Value",
            "JAN", "Quantity", "FEB", "Quantity", "MAR", "Quantity", "APR", "Quantity", "MAY", "Quantity", "JUN", "Quantity",
            "JUL", "Quantity", "AUG", "Quantity", "SEP", "Quantity", "OCT", "Quantity", "NOV", "Quantity", "DEC", "Quantity"],
            colModel: [
                    { name: "EntryId", index: "EntryId", hidden: true },
                    { name: "Team", width: 78 }, { name: "License", width: 250, editable: true, edittype: 'select',
                        editoptions: { value: GetProducts(frcstId) }
                    },
                    { name: "UP", width: 75 },
                    { name: "Currency", width: 60 }, { name: "Quantity", width: 75 }, { name: "Value", width: 80 },
                    { name: "JAN", width: 75, hidden: true }, { name: "JAN_Quan", width: 60, hidden: true }, { name: "FEB", width: 75, hidden: true },
                    { name: "FEB_Quan", width: 60, hidden: true }, { name: "MAR", width: 75, hidden: true }, { name: "MAR_Quan", width: 60, hidden: true },
                    { name: "APR", width: 75, hidden: true }, { name: "APR_Quan", width: 60, hidden: true }, { name: "MAY", width: 75, hidden: true },
                    { name: "MAY_Quan", width: 60, hidden: true }, { name: "JUN", width: 75, hidden: true }, { name: "JUN_Quan", width: 60, hidden: true },
                    { name: "JUL", width: 75, hidden: true }, { name: "JUL_Quan", width: 60, hidden: true }, { name: "AUG", width: 75, hidden: true },
                    { name: "AUG_Quan", width: 60, hidden: true }, { name: "SEP", width: 75, hidden: true }, { name: "SEP_Quan", width: 60, hidden: true },
                    { name: "OCT", width: 75, hidden: true }, { name: "OCT_Quan", width: 60, hidden: true }, { name: "NOV", width: 75, hidden: true },
                    { name: "NOV_Quan", width: 60, hidden: true }, { name: "DEC", width: 75, hidden: true }, { name: "DEC_Quan", width: 60, hidden: true }
                    ],
            id: 'EntryId',
            height: '100%',
            loadComplete: function () {
                $(".ui-jqgrid-hdiv", "#gbox_" + this.id).hide();

                var tempIdx = colStructObject.AppliedGrids.indexOf('#' + this.id);
                if (tempIdx > -1)
                    colStructObject.AppliedGrids.splice(tempIdx, 1);
                colStructObject.AppliedGrids.push('#' + this.id);

                tempIdx = editableGrids.indexOf('#' + this.id);
                if (tempIdx > -1)
                    editableGrids.splice(tempIdx, 1);
                editableGrids.push('#' + this.id);

                hideCols();
                opeEditCols();
                //setHiddenCols('#' + this.id);
            },
            cmTemplate: { sortable: false, editable: false },
            loadonce: true,
            postData: { budgetId: frcstId, divisionId: team, productType: 1 },
            width: 'auto',
            loadonce: true,
            pager: pager_id,
            rowList: [],
            pgbuttons: false,
            pgtext: null,
            viewrecords: false,
            'cellEdit': true,
            'cellsubmit': 'remote',
            cellurl: "WebServices/WS_MonthlyFrcst.asmx/CellUpdate",
            afterSaveCell: function (a, b, c, d, e) {
                $("#" + subgrid_table_id).trigger("reloadGrid");
                $("#tble_DevitMnth").trigger("reloadGrid");
                $("#tbl_GrandTotal").trigger("reloadGrid");
            },
            beforeSubmitCell: function (rowid, cellname, value, iRow, iCol) {
                if (!isNumber(value))
                    restoreCell(iRow, iCol);
            }
            //'Handler.ashx?function=UpdateCell'
        });

        $("#" + subgrid_table_id).jqGrid('navGrid', "#" + pager_id, { del: false, edit: false, refresh: true, search: false, add: false });
        $("#" + subgrid_table_id).jqGrid('navGrid', "#" + pager_id).jqGrid('navButtonAdd', "#" + pager_id, {
            caption: '', buttonicon: "ui-icon-plus",
            onClickButton: function () {
                //var emptyItem = [{ Cat_Id: catId, Category: catNm, Team: "T1", TotalAmount: amount}];
                $("#" + subgrid_table_id).jqGrid('addRowData', 0, [{}]);
                // $("#dialog").dialog("open");
                //                    $.ajax({
                //                        dataType: "json",
                //                        url: 'Handler.ashx?function=AddEmpty&Team=' + team
                //                    });

                //$("#" + subgrid_table_id).trigger("reloadGrid");
            },
            position: "first", title: "Add New Row", cursor: "pointer"
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use `cellEdit: true` option **in subgrid** and the subgrid don't contain any column with `key: true` property. Probably you need to add `key: true` to `EntryId` column? It can be that including `jsonReader: {id: "EntryId"}` in the subgrid will solve the problem alternatively. In the case you can even remove not required hidden column `EntryId` from the subgrid.

Comment: Yes, I replaced it with {id: "EntryId"} but still the same issue, I don't however understand what you mean by removing the not required hidden column EntryId from the subgrid. "EntryId" is the primary key of my table, I still need it, any ideas?, thanks anyway...

Comment: @YMELS: The rowid will be assigned as the value of `id` attribute on every row `<tr>` of table. It's not needed to create additional hidden column `<td>` with the same data. I recommend you to use Developer Tools of IE/Chrome/Firefox and example the id attribute values of rows `<tr>` of subgrid. If you will see wrong values then you have problem **during filling the grid** and not during editing. To help you I need to know the example of the data returned from `"WebServices/WS_MonthlyFrcst.asmx/GetPlanGrouped"` (subgrid URL).

Comment: Thanks Oleg, passed it from the Web-Service like you said and worked, I don't know why "Key" did not work though, thanks a lot anyway...